# Calculating working days between 2 dates in SSRS 2016

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I am using the below code, found on this website. It somehow works but not properly when the FromDate falls on a Friday as it adds another day on top.

See the screenshot for the demonstration.
What is it wrong in the code itself?

```
= (DateDiff(DateInterval.day,Fields!FromDate.Value,Fields!UntilDate.Value)+1)
- (DateDiff(DateInterval.WeekOfYear,Fields!FromDate.Value,Fields!UntilDate.Value)*2)
- IIF(Weekday(Fields!FromDate.Value,1) = 1,1,0)
- IIF(Weekday(Fields!FromDate.Value,1) = 7,1,0)
- IIF(Weekday(Fields!UntilDate.Value,1) = 1,1,0)
- IIF(Weekday(Fields!UntilDate.Value,1) = 7,1,0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

In my case I had to introduce the `CDate(format(Fields!FromDate.Value,"MM-dd-yyyy"))` in order for the days to be calculated correctly

```
I had to use the CDATE() in the code:
=(DateDiff(DateInterval.day,CDate(format(Fields!FromDate.Value,"MM-dd-yyyy")), 
CDate(format(Fields!UntilDate.Value,"MM-dd-yyyy")))+1)
-(DateDiff(DateInterval.WeekOfYear,CDate(format(Fields!FromDate.Value,"MM-dd-yyyy")), 
CDate(format(Fields!UntilDate.Value,"MM-dd-yyyy")))*2) 
- IIF(Weekday( CDate(format(Fields!FromDate.Value,"MM-dd-yyyy")),1) = 1,1,0)
- IIF(Weekday( CDate(format(Fields!FromDate.Value,"MM-dd-yyyy")),1) = 7,1,0)
- IIF(Weekday( CDate(format(Fields!UntilDate.Value,"MM-dd-yyyy")),1) = 1,1,0)
- IIF(Weekday( CDate(format(Fields!UntilDate.Value,"MM-dd-yyyy")),1) = 7,1,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is OK. The problem is that your computer may be using a different First Day of Week in the Region and Language settings than the computer that the code was made on (or mine).

[image]

To test, set a text box to `=WEEKDAY(TODAY)`. The computer this code works on has 1 as Sunday, which would make today (Wednesday) a **4**. My guess is that you get 3.

If your first day of the week is Monday, you'd need to change the weekdays to 6 and 7 rather than 1 and 7 that it currently uses.

```
= (DateDiff(DateInterval.day,Parameters!START.Value,Parameters!END.Value)+1)
- (DateDiff(DateInterval.WeekOfYear,Parameters!START.Value,Parameters!END.Value)*2)
- IIF(Weekday(Parameters!START.Value,1) = 6,1,0)
- IIF(Weekday(Parameters!START.Value,1) = 7,1,0)
- IIF(Weekday(Parameters!END.Value,1) = 6,1,0)
- IIF(Weekday(Parameters!END.Value,1) = 7,1,0)
```

If it's a Saturday, you'd need to use 1 and 2 as the weekend days.

Comment: Hallo @Hannover Fist I am in UK and my language settings state that Monday is the first day of the week. However, when I run `=WEEKDAY(TODAY)` then it shows 5 for today being a Thursday which reversing it back makes it 1 for Sunday ... I am confused :(

Comment: In my case I had to introduce the `CDate(format(Fields!FromDate.Value,"MM-dd-yyyy"))` in order for the days to be calculated correctly .... not sure why this was a problem.

Comment: @Bucki - apparently your date field is actually text and needs to be converted to a proper date type. You should use just `CDATE(Fields!FromDate.Value)` for the value and wrap that in a FORMAT function when you want to show the date `=FORMAT(CDATE(Fields!FromDate.Value),"MM-dd-yyyy")` or use `MM-dd-yyyy` in the FORMAT property of the text box.

Comment: I also set the FromDate property to MM-dd-yyyy format but it still did not work unless I used the `CDATE() and now it works as indented :) thanks for your feedback